# What is protected by W3C Access Control specification?

Tags: cross-domain

The purpose of this question is to confirm (or not) my understanding of the purpose of [W3C Access Control](http://dev.w3.org/2006/waf/access-control/). If I'm reading this correctly, it allows a resource to control who can access it from a page loaded from some other resource. It does not protect a page against malware injection making cross-script requests. In other words, any bad hat can create a (e.g.) restful service that cheerfully accepts stolen information, so long as it returns the headers from this spec to tell that browser that it is happy to do so. Have I missed anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding sounds correct. The CORS spec only details how code from one domain can access data from another domain, thereby getting around same-domain restrictions. The same security considerations as any other web request are still in effect with CORS, and you should trust the remote server you are loading data from. If you are implementing CORS on the server side, you should not rely on CORS as your sole security mechanism. If giving access to some protected resource, you should layer an auth mechanism such as OAuth2 on top of your CORS requests.